# What is the best way to update questions that have changed with the new release?

Tags: discussion

I ran into a [bug](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3536/why-does-json-serialization-give-different-results-when-the-sobject-is-created-f) with the JSON serializer that has been fixed in spring 13. I want to mark it somehow so someone looking at it in the future knows this was fixed. Of course, this could apply to all types of things that change between releases, limits increasing, new apex functionality being allowed (ex. lists of generic sObjects), etc.

The two options I see are:

1) Update the question (what I did)

2) Edit an answer or create a new answer saying this is working now.

What do people think?

Answer (score 6):

I think updating the question as you did is just fine; adding the same sort of **UPDATE** line to the existing accepted answer would make it just perfect.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with doing both ? Can't vote on an update!